# Equivalent alternative to Whitelisting Twilio requests in CloudFlare

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, twilio-php

My requirement:
Prevent non Twilio access to my ALB managed Application using CloudFlare.

My restrictions:
Due to the nature of Twilio's cloud design, it is not possible to whitelist access down to a set of IPs due to the wide pool of IPs a request could come from.

Possible solution:
Twilio suggest a couple of options under https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security but I don't know how to use any of these methods as a means to only allow twilio Traffic. But any designed validation must only be applied to the dns record of /api in the url to my site.

Further Info:
The underlying application is written in php.
I would prefer a CloudFlare solution over changing code in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach could be:

- Use [Cloudflare Firewall Rules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/cf-dashboard/create-edit-delete-rules) to check for the presence of `X-Twilio-Signature` on your api path (as a first, basic check), block requests that do not have it.
- Use a [Cloudflare Worker](https://workers.cloudflare.com/), configured on your API path. The worker code can read `X-Twilio-Signature` and the request data, and use the procedure described in the Twilio documentation to validate it. If it matches, forward the request to your load balancer. If it doesn't, return an error to the caller.

Also, make sure your origin server only accepts traffic from Cloudflare to prevent direct tampering.

Comment: Hi @Paolo - Thanks for the suggestions. Regarding the 1st Option, would it be possible to spoof the incoming request with the presence of the string "X-Twilio-Signature" in the incoming request?

Comment: The first option is just a quick way of blocking traffic that is clearly not expected (without that header). But it can be worked around, that is why the 2nd approach would be more robust since you actually do the validation before allowing the traffic to your ALB.

Comment: Would you agree here:

(not http.request.uri.query contains "X-Twilio-Signature" and http.request.uri ne "/twilio")

Then 'Allow'